# How to filter by categories in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have been working on a project in which a user can make a post but while filling the form the user has to answer 2 questions "what are you searching for" and "what category is this post from"; there is a limited amount of answers and depending on the questions answers the user's post has to be filtered and be posted in the selected category of the question "what category is this post from" and finally the user has to be redirected to the chosen category for the question "what are you searching for". Currently my code can just upload the posts but I dont know how will the filtering process look like on the views.py file because I am kind a newbie to django so Please any idea on this filtering process helps;)

models.py

```
CATEGORY_CHOICES = (             #I think this choices can help for the filter
    ('action', 'action'),
    ('sports', 'sports'),
)

class Mates(models.Model):    
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='usermates', unique=True)
    categories = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, default="choose...", max_length=10)   #I also think this field will help.
    req_bio = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    req_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='requestmates_pics', null=True, blank=True, default=False)
```

views.py

```
def matesmain(request):
    contents = Mates.objects.all()
    context = {
        'contents': contents,
        'form_mates': MatesForm(),
    }
    print("nice3")
    return render(request, 'mates.html', context)

def mates(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_mates = MatesForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form_mates.is_valid():
            instance = form_mates.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = request.user
            instance.save()
            return redirect('mates-main')
            print('succesfully uploded')

    else:
        form_mates = MatesForm()
        print('didnt upload')
    return redirect('mates-main')
```

forms.py

```
class MatesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Mates
        fields = ('req_bio', 'req_image',)
        exclude = ['user']
```

mates.html

```
{% for content in contents %}
    {% if not content.user == user %}
        <div class="mates-grid">
            <div class="mates-grid-1">
                <div class="mates-item">
                    <form action="{% url 'mates' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{form_mates.as_p}}
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% elif content.user == user %}
        I have my dynamic data output here
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Any questions please let me know in the comments.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Who should be able to filter, What should be filtered on and what is the desired result of filtering?

Comment: Sorry let me fix that

Comment: @Vincent I just changed changed the question, can you check it please? Is it clear now?

Comment: I’m sorry, I still don’t understand what you are trying to do. Do you have an example of where this functionality is used that I can see?

Comment: @Vincent have you used hoop from snapchat I think it is

Comment: @Vincent well hoop basically filters users by region what I want to do is filter users by categories was that clear?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter on a Model field, you can use `.filter()`. Read more about that [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/).

In a view this would look something like this;

```
from .models import Mates

def show_mates(request):
    # depending on how you want to get the category
    category = ''

    mates_for_category = Mates.objects.filter(categories=category)

    context = {
        "mates": mates_for_category
    }

    return render(request, template_name='mates_for_category.html', context=context)
```

From your question I don't understand how you want the user to be able to filter on a category, so I didn't specify that in this example.